# Combining multiple variables and displaying them correctly

Tags: javascript

I have the following code;

```
var pro = $(".pro").map(function() {
    return this.innerHTML + '(';
}).get();
var qty = $(".qty").map(function() {
    return this.value + ')\xa0';
}).get();
var total = pro + qty;
```

When I print total, it prints as PRODa(,PRODb(2) ,1). I'm trying to show it as PRODa(2) PRODb(2). Basically to put them in order, pro with the associated qty. Is this possible to do within the code above and not under some type of echo/print?

Comment: This might be easier to understand with a http://jsfiddle.net/ example that includes HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var total = $(".pro,.qty").map(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('pro'))    
        return this.innerHTML + '(';
    else
        return this.value + ')\xa0';
}).get();

alert(total);
```

hope I understood you correctly. I didn't test cuz I don't know the structure your using however should work for alternated `.pro` and `.qty`

Comment: That worked perfect! Just as I was entering the original in jsfiddle, solutions up already. Thank a lot for the amazing help, really appreciate it!